# How to use for-loop as argument in function

Tags: python-2.7, class, inheritance

```
class Diff:
    def __init__(self, f, h):
      self.f = f
      self.h = h

class Backward1(Diff):
    def __call__(self, x):
      f = self.f
      h = self.h
      return (f(x)-f(x-h))/h

from math import sin, pi
A = Backward1(sin,1E-5)
print A(pi)
```

Want to calculate for several h-values, like [h=2**(-k) for k in range(10)]. Any tips for how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign variable in list comprehensions but I don't think you need to:

```
print([Backward1(sin, 2**(-k))(pi) for k in range(10)])
```

Would construct a list of results for different `h`s.
Or a 2-step process so you can use different args for the same set of functions:

```
fns = [Backward1(sin, 2**(-k)) for k in range(10)]
print([fn(pi) for fn in fns])
print([fn(2*pi) for fn in fns])
```